# Обновление Foreground при работе программы согласно MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

Вопрос для знающих WPF.

Есть проект на основе MVVM, есть форма на которой расположен `DataGrid`, каждая строка `DataGrid` - это элемент класса. То есть `ItemsSource` `DataGrid` - это лист, так вот в этом классе есть свойство color, оно меняется во время работы программы. Мне же требуется передавать вот эту переменную в значение Foregraund каждой строки.

Сделал следующим образом: .

При первой загрузке формы все хорошо, все правильно, но при изменении Color для любой из строк, цвет не меняется.

Немного кода:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Класс для отображения товаров в журнале
    /// </summary>
    public class SaleItemsInfoGrid : MVVM.ViewModel
    {
        public Good Good { get; set; }

        public Document Document { get; set; }

        public DocumentItem Item { get; set; }

        public decimal SumItems { get; set; }

        private string _color = "Black";
        public string Color
        {
            get => _color;
            set
            {
                _color = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

ReturnCommand = new MVVM.RelayCommand(obj =>
        {
            new FrmReturnSales().ShowReturns(SelectedSale.Document);
            SaleItemsList.First(x => x == SelectedSale).Color = "Red";
        });

<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Foregraund " Value="{Binding Path=Color}"></Setter>
    </Style.Setters>            
</Style>

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            protected  void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null, bool isUpdateAllProp = false)
            {
                var propName = isUpdateAllProp ? string.Empty : propertyName;

                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
```

Comment: У меня не воспроизводится: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuOm2.gif

Comment: А можете прислать файл проекта? Сравню что у меня не так...

Comment: Не могу, т.к. не сохранял. Покажите реализацию OnPropertyChanged

Comment: Добавил, можете посмотреть в посте

Comment: Здесь проблем не видно. Пока вижу только один вариант — вы меняете цвет не того элемента, который отображается в DataGrid

Comment: Есть одна идея, сейчас попробую

Comment: Попробуйте у привязанной коллекции просто сделать `MyItems[0].Color = "Red";`

Comment: Да, так сработало, но цвет меняется только после нажатия на какую либо из строк, то есть при выделении.